# What is right term for pure frontend + REST backend web sites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, backbone.js, web

Most of sites which I'm working on are:

- jquery/backbone/undescore + underscore templates (async loaded or static loaded)
- rest webservices with backbone models
- one page with location hash router to link application state with url

I know there are plenty of other frameworks which support similar approach (canjs, angular, ember, mustache templating, etc.)

And recently I've found difficulty to describe this paradigm to people which are still think that web applications UI should be mostly backend-controlled (i.e. like in struts/tapestry/stripes with optional ajaxifications).

So, what is right umbrella term for those web development approach which I've described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that the agreed upon term for it is a [Single-page Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).